# TEXT_DETECTION ignoring / eliminating words

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am experimenting with the Google Vision API text detection feature, and trying to perform OCR on text images. The text images are quite clean and it works 80% of the times. The 20% of errors include misinterpreted numbers / characters (fixable), and some words / numbers that simply don't show up (not fixable!).

I followed the best practices page tips (image is 1024x768, 16-bit PNG) with no avail.

Here is an example: this sample page
https://storage.googleapis.com/ximian-cloud.appspot.com/sample_page.png

Has a number 177 (Under observations, right of "RT ARM") and this is not detected at all by the API ...

I tried:

- Twice the resolution (2048 x 1536)
- BMP 24-bit
- BMP 32-bit
- All of the above, in grayscale
- All of the above, inverted (black background and white letters)

No luck ...

Any hint on why this is happening? Is it the API or my image format could use some formatting?

Comment: Same problem here... The funny is that "Try this API" tool (https://cloud.google.com/vision/) recognizes my image properly but when I query the API myself it misses some obvious words :((

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same problem as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117524/why-gcp-vision-api-returns-worse-results-in-python-than-at-its-online-demo. Please, confirm.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that has been noticed and registered already, now in the process of getting fixed, hopefully quite soon.

Comment: Friendly ping - I just tested this again and it's still not working (v1). Is this fixed in v1.1? How can I access the beta? Thanks