# Google Vision | Vietnamese: Low Quality OCR Results

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ocr

**Background**

Using Google Vision API (with Node) to recognize Vietnamese text, the result is lacking quality. There are some (not all but some) tone markers as well as vowel signifies missing.

Compared to their online demo, which returns a decent result (scroll down for live demo):

https://cloud.google.com/vision/

(As I do not have a company account with them, I cannot ask Google directly.)

**Question**

Can I tweak my request to get better results?

I already set the language hint to "vi" and tried to combine it with "en". I also tried the more specific "vi-VN".

**Example Image**

https://www.tecc.org/Slatwall/custom/assets/images/product/default/cache/j056vt-_800w_800h_sb.jpg

**Example Code**

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");

async function quickstart() {
  let text;
  const fileName = "j056vt-_800w_800h_sb.jpg";
  const imageFile = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
  const image = Buffer.from(imageFile).toString("base64");
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  const request = {
    image: {
      content: image
    },
    imageContext: {
      languageHints: ["vi", 'en']
    }
  };

  const [result] = await client.textDetection(request);

  for (const tmp of result.textAnnotations) {
    text += tmp.description + '\n';
  }

  const out = path.basename(fileName, path.extname(fileName)) + ".txt";
  fs.writeFileSync(out, text);
}

quickstart();
```

## Solution

```js
// $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");

async function quickstart() {
  let text = '';
  const fileName = "j056vt-_800w_800h_sb.jpg";
  const imageFile = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
  const image = Buffer.from(imageFile).toString("base64");
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  const request = {
    image: {
      content: image
    },
    imageContext: {
      languageHints: ["vi-VN"]
    }
  };

  const [result] = await client.documentTextDetection(request);

  // OUTPUT METHOD A

  for (const tmp of result.textAnnotations) {
      text += tmp.description + "\n";
  }

  console.log(text);

  const out = path.basename(fileName, path.extname(fileName)) + ".txt";
  fs.writeFileSync(out, text);

  // OUTPUT METHOD B

  const fullTextAnnotation = result.fullTextAnnotation;
  console.log(`Full text: ${fullTextAnnotation.text}`);
  fullTextAnnotation.pages.forEach(page => {
    page.blocks.forEach(block => {
      console.log(`Block confidence: ${block.confidence}`);
      block.paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
        console.log(`Paragraph confidence: ${paragraph.confidence}`);
        paragraph.words.forEach(word => {
          const wordText = word.symbols.map(s => s.text).join("");
          console.log(`Word text: ${wordText}`);
          console.log(`Word confidence: ${word.confidence}`);
          word.symbols.forEach(symbol => {
            console.log(`Symbol text: ${symbol.text}`);
            console.log(`Symbol confidence: ${symbol.confidence}`);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });

}

quickstart();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already answered [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117524/why-gcp-vision-api-returns-worse-results-in-python-than-at-its-online-demo).

In summary, the Demo is in this case probably using the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION, which can sometimes make a more thorough strings extraction, while you are using TEXT_DETECTION.

You can try to make a client.document_text_detection request instead of client.textDetection and you will probably get results closer to the Demo.

If you want to read to the related documentation you can find it [here.](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)

I hope this resolves your question!

Comment: Yikes, I was mentally biased by the idea that DOCUMENT applies to dense text only. That solved it, thanks!